# Parsing json string in iOS Objective C

Tags: iphone, ios, json

I am trying to build my first iOS app that parses json from a web service.

In my .h file i create an array

```
NSArray *items;
```

In my .m file i call the website and store the data into the array. This all goes fine except eventually I am trying to display the data in a uitableview.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemsCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    NSLog(@"%@",items);

    NSDictionary *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *title = [item objectForKey:@"title"];

    cell.title.text = title;

    return cell;
}
```

The nslog of items produces:

```
{
category = code;
keyword = "";
limit = 20;
lowPrice = "";
page = 0;
products =     (
    {
        description = "...";
        mobileFriendly = 1;
        popularity = 2021;
        productId = code;
        title = "title";
    }, and so on...
)
```

I am getting an error trying to do NSDictionary *item = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; It says doing objectAtIndex:indexPath.row is invalid.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value stored in `items` is an instance of `NSDictionary`, but you're sending it an `NSArray` message. Also, the code you posted is referring to `gift` and ignoring the item anyway.

The array you're looking for is actually stored under the key `products` inside the `items` dictionary, so you need to do something like this:

```
NSArray *products = [items objectForKey:@"products"];

NSDictionary *product = [products objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
// Then use the product, instead of using 'gift' (whatever that is).
NSString *title = [product objectForKey:@"title"];
```

Answer (score 0):

items is not a `NSArray` - it is a `NSDictionary`.  so it has no `objectAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: so if i change the header file to be NSDictionary *items... how would i get to accessing the products? thanks!